# How can you transfer balances from one accountId to another in substrate runtime?

Tags: transfer

How can you transfer balances from one accountId to another in substrate runtime?

```
#[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1))]
pub fn my_transfer(origin: OriginFor<T>,  account: T::AccountId, amount: u64) -> DispatchResult {
            let owner = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            match PalletDataStore::<T>::get() {
                Some(destination) => {
                    let _ = Currency::transfer(&owner, &destination, amount, ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive);
                },
                None => return Err(Error::<T>::NoneValue.into()),
            };
}
```

1. Based on the code above, I need to transfer some amount of origin's balances to some destination account
2. I got an error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
cannot satisfy `_: Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>`
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now solved.  The solution is as follows:

1. Add the following code in your pub trait Config: frame_system::Config

```
type Currency: Currency<Self::AccountId>;
```

2. Set the value of the config trait in runtime to point to pallet_balances

```
type Currency = pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>;
```

3. Declare a type BalanceOf (Reference: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/monthly-2021-09+1/pallet_balances/index.html)

```
pub type BalanceOf<T> = <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
```

4. Now modify your code:

```
#[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1))]
pub fn my_transfer(origin: OriginFor<T>,  source: T::AccountId, amount: BalanceOf<T>) -> DispatchResult {
      let owner = ensure_signed(origin)?;
      match PalletDataStore::<T>::get() {
          Some(destination) => {
              T::Currency::transfer(&source, &destination, amount, ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive)?;
          },
          None => return Err(Error::<T>::NoneValue.into()),
      };
      Ok(())
}
```

Comment: if you have hardcoupled pallet_balances and already have `Balance` type defined - use this call for transfer instead `<pallet_balances::Pallet<T> as Currency<_>>::transfer()`